# Создание элемента оглавления, отступ которого подстраивается под предыдущий элемент

Tags: latex, tex

Создание элемента оглавления, отступ которого подстраивается под предыдущий элемент.
Т.е. (что я имею ввиду?):
Требуется чтобы следующий код:

```
\section{S1}
\paragraph{P1}
\section{S2}
\subsection{S3}
\paragraph{P2}
```

Выдавал в оглавлении нечто следующее:

```
1.1 S1
    $1 P1
1.2 S2
    1.2.1 S3
          $1 P2
```

(Решение есть, но решение крайне костыльное, хотелось бы чего-нибудь получше)
Костыльное решение:

```
\makeatletter
\newcounter{paragraphl}[subsubsection]
\newcommand{\paragraphl}{\@startsection{paragraphl}{4}{0pt}{1em}{1em}{\Large\bf}}
\renewcommand{\theparagraphl}{\S\ \@arabic\c@paragraphl}
\newcommand*{\l@paragraphl}{\@dottedtocline{4}{3.75em}{2em}}
\newcommand{\paragraphlmark}[1]{}
\newcounter{subparagraphl}[paragraphl]
\newcommand{\subparagraphl}{\@startsection{subparagraphl}{5}{0pt}{1em}{1em}{\Large\bf}}
\renewcommand{\thesubparagraphl}{\S\ \@arabic\c@paragraphl.\@arabic\c@subparagraphl}
\newcommand*{\l@subparagraphl}{\@dottedtocline{5}{5.75em}{3em}}
\newcommand{\subparagraphlmark}[1]{}

\newcounter{paragraphll}[subsubsection]
\newcommand{\paragraphll}{\@startsection{paragraphll}{4}{0pt}{1em}{1em}{\Large\bf}}
\renewcommand{\theparagraphll}{\S\ \@arabic\c@paragraphll}
\newcommand*{\l@paragraphll}{\@dottedtocline{4}{7em}{2em}}
\newcommand{\paragraphllmark}[1]{}
\newcounter{subparagraphll}[paragraphll]
\newcommand{\subparagraphll}{\@startsection{subparagraphll}{5}{0pt}{1em}{1em}{\Large\bf}}
\renewcommand{\thesubparagraphll}{\S\ \@arabic\c@paragraphll.\@arabic\c@subparagraphll}
\newcommand*{\l@subparagraphll}{\@dottedtocline{5}{9em}{3em}}
\newcommand{\subparagraphllmark}[1]{}

\newcommand{\SetL}{\renewcommand{\paragraph}{\paragraphl}\renewcommand{\subparagraph}{\subparagraphl}}
\newcommand{\SetLL}{\renewcommand{\paragraph}{\paragraphll}\renewcommand{\subparagraph}{\subparagraphll}}

\renewcommand{\section}{\SetL\@startsection{section}{1}{0pt}{1em}{1em}{\Large\bf}}
\renewcommand{\subsection}{\SetLL\@startsection{subsection}{2}{0pt}{1em}{1em}{\Large\bf}}

\makeatother
```

Заключается в создании двух видов параграфа с нужными отступами и переопределении базового параграфа "налету".

Comment: К слову, я пробовал создать длину и устанавливать её значение внутри команд \section и \subsection но это не приводит ни к чему